# WSO2 : application and users

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I've created an application as "admin". Now, I create a "demo" user, and give him all roles and all permissions for this app. When I connect with "demo" I can't even see the application created by "admin".

Is this a feature ? or just a misconfiguration ? (but I don't see what config is left).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the default behavior. If you want to share applications/subscriptions among users, you have to enable the sharing feature. See [Sharing Applications and Subscriptions](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Sharing+Applications+and+Subscriptions) docs for that.

Shared apps will be listed like this.

[image]

EDIT to make this the validated answer :

This whole paragraph from the documentation has to be written differently because it's wrong and very confusing. There is no "**default**" strategy of grouping, you have to alter the **default** configuration to activate it :

> **By default**, the API Manager considers the organization name that you give at the time you sign up to the API Store as the group ID. It extracts the claim http://wso2.org/claims/organization of a user and uses the value specified in it as the group ID. This way, all users who specify the same organization name belong to the same group and therefore, can view each others' subscriptions and applications. The API Manager also provides flexibility to change this default authentication implementation

Comment: After reading this doc, I've edited user profiles in carbon UI (admin and demo default profil) to give them the same Organization. "demo" user still can't see the app created by "admin" user.

Comment: Can you create a new application and see?

Comment: When I create a new app with "demo", I can't see it when I login with "admin".

Comment: I just configured the same and apps created after that are shared properly. I updated my answer with a screenshot. Are you trying this on a distributed setup or a single node?

Comment: If you configured it properly, in `AM_APPLICATION` table of `WSO2AM_DB` database, `GROUP_ID` of the entry corresponding  to your new app should have a not null value. Please check that.

Comment: I am running the most basic single node installation and I have not installed any database. Is the relational model between apps and users change depending on how you install the product ? Or is this a bug related to this kind of installation ?

Comment: No, the relational data model does not depend on the deployment pattern. I just wanted to make sure it's not a caching issue. If it was a distributed deployment it could be a caching issue. I also used a single pack (with default H2 database) to verify it's working above. It's strange that it's not working for you. Could you please double check the steps you followed?